# not working Selenium Webdriver C# Sendkeys (Keys.control+"t") for newtab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create new tab this.windowfirefox in selenium c#

try with 3 solution but not working for me.

firefox and webdrive is last verison and update.

.netframework 4.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading;

namespace Testselenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var drive3 = new FirefoxDriver();
            drive3.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

            IWebElement element21 = drive3.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
           // element21.Click();
             element21.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
            // element21.SendKeys(Keys.LeftControl + "t");
             //element21.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "T");



        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to open new tab using JavaScriptExecutor:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)drive3;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('http://www.google.com');");
```

This should allow you to open Google main page in new tab. If you want to open empty page - just don't pass arguments to `window.open()`

Comment: thanks my friend,document?

Comment: You don't need to cast to `IJavaScriptExecutor`, the driver has built in `ExecuteJavaScript` method `driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("");`